# how to specify /schedule a certain task in laravel based on certain day

Tags: laravel

I'm really new to laravel and I want to know what techniques are used in this problem/application of mine.

Suppose there is a pizza delivery and once a user has placed his order. That order is repeated depending on what the restaurant administrator specifies what day is it in a month? Any ideas on this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do something every month on the 4th at 15:00, you should add in `app/Console/Kernel.php` in `schedule` method:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
     // Do something, send pizza, etc.
})->monthlyOn(4, '15:00');
```

More information here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#defining-schedules